# Render cards from external JSON in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm very new to **Ionic** and I currently started a test project to build an app that **reads JSON from external** server through **http** request. By following the tutorial **I can fetch the JSON now** but I found no proper tutorial mentoring **how to render cards into the page**. My code is at below:

I need some **practical** ideas of how to render the cards.

> pages/home/home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <button ion-button block (click)="fetchResult()">Fetch External Data</button>
  <ion-cards>
      <ion-card>
          <img src="img/image-url-from-json.png"/>
          <ion-card-content>
            <ion-card-title>
              Card Title
              </ion-card-title>
            <p>
              Card content from JSON goes here
            </p>
          </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
  </ion-cars>
</ion-content>
```

> pages/home/home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    posts: any;

  constructor(
    private http: HTTP,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController
  ) {};

  fetchResult() {
      this.http.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/top/.json?limit=10&sort=hot', {}, {})
      .then(data => {
        this.posts = data.data.children;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.showError(error.status, error.error);
      });
  };

  showError(title, msg) {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: title,
      subTitle: msg,
      buttons: ['Close']
    });
    alert.present();
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you made a typo: `ion-cars` should be `ion-cards`. Besides that, you can just use the `ngFor` directive: `<ion-card *ngFor="let post of posts"><img [src]="post.imgUrl" />..</ion-card>`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my typo, also thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *ngFor to dynamically create cards. [Angular template syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax)

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let post of posts">
  <img src="{{post.img}}"/>
  <ion-card-content>
    <ion-card-title>
      Card Title
      </ion-card-title>
    <p>
      {{post.content}}
    </p>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: You are using a promise when the http.get returns an Observable. you should either use that observable or call the toPromise function of an observable.

Comment: In ionic the http-service methods get/post return a promise. https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/